# RuntimeWarning: PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, pygtk

I'm using PyGTK for Python 2.7 in Ubuntu 14.04, but I get the following message:

```
RuntimeWarning: PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK
```

What could be the reason ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

When does it trigger? Are you trying to run some script or just use PyGTK interactively?

Most likely, your input hook is grabbed by another interactive loop, e.g.:

```
>>> import Tkinter
>>> root = Tkinter.Tk() # input hook is grabbed by Tkinter for immediate result evaluation
>>> import gtk          # gtk tries to grab the hook, but fails
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:127: RuntimeWarning: PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK
```

The *immediate result evaluation* means that an expression results are evaluated immediately (e.g. window is displayed) before entering the main loop.

Have in mind, that this is a warning, not an error, but if it bothers you,
you can import gtk module as early as you can (or, well, reasonably early) and release the input hook:

```
import gtk
gtk.set_interactive(False)
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()
# no warning here
```

Comment: Don't help me, because I'm getting this message at the moment of importing `gtk` - on line `set_interactive(1)` in `gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py`

Comment: @Jury This is expected, if you import `Tkinter` before `gtk`.

Comment: I don't use `Tkinter` in my project, just `gtk`, but I got the same error

Comment: @Jury: well, then you _do_ use something, that competes with `gtk` for the interactive eval loop. You could provide your `import` section at the very least.

Comment: FTR this answer got rid of the error message when I was using `tkinter` and needed to `import gtk` so I could use `clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()`. An image didn't come through as expected though but that's a different problem!